# Cant send response when in apt.get() body have function with while loop

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events

im struggling with this issue for couple of hours, so ive decided to ask You for some help. Here is my nodejs code:

```
var SSE = require('sse-nodejs');

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var httpsServer = require('https').createServer();

var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/berskik/sse/notification/:usrDir', function (req,res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    var app = SSE(res);
    var path = "../static/resources/users_files/" + req.params["usrDir"];
    var fileName = "";
    fileName = waitAndReturnUploadedFileName(path);
    sendEvent(app, fileName, res);
});

app.listen(4650, function () {
    console.log('Notification SSE Server has succesfully started at port 4650.');
});

function msleep(n) {
  Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, n);
}

function readDir(path){
    return fs.readdirSync(path);
}

function sendEvent(app, fileName, res){
    console.log("Sending notification.");
    app.send({"notify": fileName});
    console.log("Notification has been sent.");
}

function waitAndReturnUploadedFileName(path) {
    var newFile = "";
    var breakFlag = false;
    var oldItems = readDir(path);
    while(!breakFlag){
        var items = readDir(path);
        console.log(items.length + "  " + oldItems.length);
        if(items.length > oldItems.length){
            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                console.log(!oldItems.includes(items[i]));
                if(!oldItems.includes(items[i])){
                    newFile = items[i];
                    breakFlag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        oldItems = items;
        msleep(1800);
    }
    console.log("New file has been found.");
    return newFile
}
```

And my problem is that when I comment or delete

```
fileName = waitAndReturnUploadedFileName(path);
```

that is actually whole-logic function, app.send() works perfectly, but when i have got this function in my code then nothing is being sent, even if all the other functions (including console.log()) are executing.

I'll appreciate every answer.

Comment: Look at the code block and see if you can determine any way for `breakFlag` to never get updated. Basically: what is this code supposed to do, according to you, and what does it _actually_ do? Also, note that there is no "sleep" in JS, because that would completely lock up the entire single threaded JS execution environment. I don't know what msleep(...) does, but I'm guessinging it's a "milliseconds sleep" instruction, and you _really_ don't want it there. Or anywhere in JS code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah, im sure that it escapes loop after searching for new file in dir is over, because all console logs (that are after and before loop function are being printed and its sync func)

Comment: No, that was a hint: there is only one place where you change `breakFlag`, and there are plenty of ways to _not_ ever reach that line, so you'll never exit the while loop, and you've now successfully locked up your server. Instead of "waiting for a file", just do what servers do: check for the file. If it's not there, you return a 404. If it's there, you return 200 with that file, or its metadata, or whatever the file was needed for.